# Within the cluster, there are several individual machines whose memory continues to increase until it exceeds 85%.how to resolve?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Within the cluster, there are several individual machines whose memory continues to increase until the alarm.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Compare abnormal machines with problematic machines, some info show：

abnormal machine：

- [top show mem 10gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR3BM.png)
- java Native memeory show commit 9479MB:

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=10651MB, committed=9479MB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=7168MB, committed=7168MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=7168MB, committed=7168MB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=1147MB, committed=140MB)
                            (classes #22587)
                            (malloc=3MB #50903) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1144MB, committed=137MB) 
 
-                    Thread (reserved=1020MB, committed=1020MB)
                            (thread #1013)
                            (stack: reserved=1016MB, committed=1016MB)
                            (malloc=3MB #5073) 
                            (arena=1MB #2021)
 
-                      Code (reserved=262MB, committed=112MB)
                            (malloc=18MB #26576) 
                            (mmap: reserved=244MB, committed=93MB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=354MB, committed=354MB)
                            (malloc=56MB #58554) 
                            (mmap: reserved=298MB, committed=298MB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=2MB, committed=2MB)
                            (malloc=2MB #4614) 
 
-                  Internal (reserved=649MB, committed=649MB)
                            (malloc=649MB #66342) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=26MB, committed=26MB)
                            (malloc=24MB #242279) 
                            (arena=2MB #1)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=7MB, committed=7MB)
                            (tracking overhead=7MB)
 
-                   Unknown (reserved=14MB, committed=0MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=14MB, committed=0MB)
```

---

normal machine

- [top show mem 8.1gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Hi5.png)
- java Native memeory show commit 9291MB:

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=10465MB, committed=9291MB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=7168MB, committed=7168MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=7168MB, committed=7168MB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=1140MB, committed=132MB)
                            (classes #20844)
                            (malloc=4MB #50411) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1136MB, committed=128MB) 
 
-                    Thread (reserved=1087MB, committed=1087MB)
                            (thread #1079)
                            (stack: reserved=1082MB, committed=1082MB)
                            (malloc=3MB #5403) 
                            (arena=1MB #2153)
 
-                      Code (reserved=262MB, committed=110MB)
                            (malloc=18MB #25669) 
                            (mmap: reserved=244MB, committed=92MB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=333MB, committed=333MB)
                            (malloc=35MB #38960) 
                            (mmap: reserved=298MB, committed=298MB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=3MB, committed=3MB)
                            (malloc=3MB #5355) 
 
-                  Internal (reserved=427MB, committed=427MB)
                            (malloc=427MB #50809) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=24MB, committed=24MB)
                            (malloc=22MB #227078) 
                            (arena=2MB #1)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=6MB, committed=6MB)
                            (tracking overhead=6MB)
 
-                   Unknown (reserved=14MB, committed=0MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=14MB, committed=0MB)
```

The abnormal machine top shows that it takes up 10g of memory, and the normal machine shows 8.1 g. However, the java memory stack shows that the memory consumption on both sides is not much different. The whole thing looks normal, but the memory footprint of abnormal machines is very high.

---

Check the stack situation, it seems that the memory occupation of the whole stack is basically the same as that of normal machines, abnormal machines will have several times full gc, but this does not seem to be a problem.

```
abnormal machine:jstat -gc 1954
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
 0.0   262144.0  0.0   262144.0 3637248.0 425984.0 3440640.0  2568134.1  140052.0 123958.6 18452.0 15316.6  12853  585.804   3     27.154  612.958



normal machine:jstat -gc 1973
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
 0.0   163840.0  0.0   163840.0 4194304.0 1605632.0 2981888.0  2257346.5  131496.0 114735.3 17356.0 14088.7  10696  336.754   0      0.000  336.754
```

The entire stack takes up to 7 gigabytes, but java process memory usage has exceeded 10 gigabytes and continues to increase.

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible there's a memory leak in the application. You won't find it by looking at `top`. Make a full dump of the application and analyze it. You can find tools to help by googling "java memory dump".

Comment: I checked GC and it was basically normal.